# In Scala, how can I reassign tuple values?

Tags: scala

I'm trying to do something like the following

```
var tuple = (1, "test")
tuple._2 = "new"
```

However this does not compile it complains about val

Comment: I'm looking at http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Tuple3 and I still cannot see the copy option

Comment: The copy method is introduced automatically because `Tuple3` is a `case class`.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You can't reassign tuple values.  They're intentionally immutable: once you have created a tuple, you can be confident that it will never change.  This is very useful for writing correct code!

But what if you want a different tuple?  That's where the copy method comes in:

```
val tuple = (1, "test")
val another = tuple.copy(_2 = "new")
```

or if you really want to use a var to contain the tuple:

```
var tuple = (1, "test")
tuple = tuple.copy(_2 = "new")
```

Alternatively, if you really, really want your values to change individually, you can use a case class instead (probably with an implicit conversion so you can get a tuple when you need it):

```
case class Doublet[A,B](var _1: A, var _2: B) {}
implicit def doublet_to_tuple[A,B](db: Doublet[A,B]) = (db._1, db._2)
val doublet = Doublet(1, "test")
doublet._2 = "new"
```

Comment: Hi Rex, you mentioned a while back you were working on a library with `Muple` types and other mutable collections. It would be great to see it on Github!

Comment: @Kipton Barros - Yeah, wouldn't it?  I wish I had time to finish it up.  I ran into a bunch of specialization bugs and then ran out of time to work around them.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrapper the component(s) you need to modify in a case class with a `var` member, like:

```
case class Ref[A](var value: A)

var tuple = (Ref(1), "test")
tuple._1.value = 2
println(tuple._1.value) // -> 2
```

Comment: Using a `case class` seems like a bit of an overkill if all you want out of it is to avoid `new Ref(1)`.