# How can I overwrite the values of a tuple in scala?

Tags: scala

I tried to overwrite the tuple values in scala using

```
val item = (1,'A',1);
item._1=2;
```

But I got an error 'reassignment to value'. Then I used stackoverflow "[In Scala, how can I reassign tuple values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7142838/in-scala-how-can-i-reassign-tuple-values)" and found the following solution:

```
val item = (1,'A',1);
item = item.copy(_1,2);
```

But I am getting the same error 'reassignment to value'. I tried with both val and var keyword.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A tuple in Scala is immutable, i.e. you can't change it values.

The second version goes in the correct direction, but you should use it like this:

```
 var item = (1, 'A',1); 
 item = item.copy(_1 = 2);
```

I.e. you make it a `var` not a `val` so you can reassign it.

Comment: Then I got an error 'not found :value_1'

Comment: It should be `item.copy(_1 = 2)`.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov correct. Fixed it.

Comment: @ThulasiAccot might be due to the mistake Alexey pointed out. try the revised version

Comment: This is the same as in the linked-to question, only with less information.

Comment: Thank you .. Fixed it. Actually I am very new to scala So didnt notice the syntax error.