# How do I assign value to an Integer in a tuple in scala?

Tags: scala

If I type the following code,

```
var x = ("This is driving me nuts!", 38)
x._2 = 58
```

I get the following error.

```
error: reassignment to val
         x._2 = 58
```

How can I solve this problem? I mean, how can I be able to assign a new value to that second element of the tuple.

Comment: You can't but you can create an update copy of the tuple: `x.copy(_2 = 58)` or `val newTuple = x._1 -> 58`. P.S. It's recommanded to have a look at immutability.

Comment: I see. At this moment, it would be enough to have an Integer class in which we can set values by using a method. Is there any such class in Scala. I saw the Integer class, and it doesn't have any set method.

Comment: You really should not do that. That's far from being the way to do it in Scala.

Comment: I see. copy here means that If I use an object, only its reference would be copied, right?

Comment: No, `copy` doesn't just copy a reference, it creates a new object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't, because tuples are immutable.

Instead, create a new tuple and assign that to `x`:

```
x = (x._1, 58)
```

The "Scala way" of doing things (best practice) is to keep everything immutable as much as possible. This includes: use `var` (mutable variables) only when you have a good reason; otherwise, use `val` (immutable values).

Comment: or `x.copy(_2 = 58)`. More practical if your tuple contains more than 2 elements

Comment: Is there a class which behaves like Integer but has a method to change value of that integer through the set method. In that way, I can still use this  immutable tuple.

Comment: @pythonic no, there is no standard mutable `Int` holder type. You could easily create it yourself (`class IntHolder(var x: Int)`) but why do you insist on having mutable data this way? It's not good practice.

Comment: Nice write-up of best practices - [Keeping Scala Simple](http://underscore.io/blog/posts/2015/06/25/keeping-scala-simple.html) by underscore.io

Answer (score 0):

Here is a similar question:

[In Scala, how can I reassign tuple values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7142838/in-scala-how-can-i-reassign-tuple-values)

As covered by Jesper, tuples are immutable and you should create a new one.  I'm not sure its any more concise than his answer, but there is also a copy method on tuples, and you can use it just like you would be a standard case class.

```
var tuple = (1, "test")
tuple = tuple.copy(_2 = "new")
```