# Copy method(Scala Tuple) not working as desired

Tags: scala, tuples

Going by the answer given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7142838/in-scala-how-can-i-reassign-tuple-values)

> You can't reassign tuple values. They're intentionally immutable: once you have created a tuple, you can be confident that it will never change. This is very useful for writing correct code!
>   But what if you want a different tuple? That's where the copy method comes in:

```
 val tuple = (1, "test")
 val another = tuple.copy(_2 = "new")
```

When I run the below code

```
 var TupleOne=("One", 2, true)
 println(TupleOne._1) //Gives One(As desired)

 var TupleTwo=("Two", TupleOne.copy(_1 = "new"),false)
 println(TupleTwo._2) //Gives (new,2,true)->weird
```

As per my understanding the second tuple should be `("Two","new",false)` and printing `TupleTwo._2` should give `"new"`

Why the behavior is different here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TupleOne.copy(_1 = "new")` is `("One", "new", true)`. So when you put it into a tuple, `TupleTwo` is `("Two", ("One", "new", true), false)`. And `TupleTwo._2` is of course `("One", "new", true)` again. (You don't get the quotes `"` when they are printed, because that's how `toString` on `String` is defined.)

Comment: As pointed by you , a new tuple getting created as per the example. To call the desired element from tuple , the tuple should be called in a nested fashion.
Here is exactly what got me out of confusion  var TupleOne=("One",2,true)
println(TupleOne._1)
var TupleTwo=("Two",TupleOne.copy(_1 = "new"),false)
println(TupleTwo._2._2) . Now the answer is as desired.

Answer (score 0):

**1) You don't even need `.copy`** based on your example.

you have

```
var TupleOne=("One", 2, true)
```

you are expecting

```
var TupleTwo = ("Two","new",false)
```

Theres nothing to be copied `tupleOne`.

The other thing is `.copy` returns type of instance that you are copying from, which is `Tuple` too

Example to copy first element but mutate second element.

```
scala> val tupleOne = ("copyme", "dont-copy-me")
tupleOne: (String, String) = (copyme,dont-copy-me)

scala> val tupleTwo = tupleOne.copy(_2 = "I'm new")
tupleTwo: (String, String) = (copyme,I'm new)
```

**2) Lets go to your example,**

```
scala> val TupleOne=("One",2,true)
TupleOne: (String, Int, Boolean) = (One,2,true)
```

To get your expected result, you have to alter each element of `TupleOne` as below which makes no sense because you are copying nothing.

```
scala> TupleOne.copy(_1= "Two", _2 = "new", _3= false)
res3: (String, String, Boolean) = (Two,new,false)
```

3) Again, since `Tuple.copy` returns `Tuple`, your `TupleTwo` is `Tuple` inside `Tuple`. **(#2 is what you probably looking for)**

```
scala> var TupleOne=("One",2,true)
TupleOne: (String, Int, Boolean) = (One,2,true)

scala> var TupleTwo=("Two",TupleOne.copy(_1 = "new"),false)
TupleTwo: (String, (String, Int, Boolean), Boolean) = (Two,(new,2,true),false)
```