# How to modify a value to Tuple2 in Java

Tags: java, scala, apache-flink, final, accumulator

I am using a accumulator within a fold function. I would like to change the value of the accumulator.

My function looks something like this:

```
public Tuple2<String, Long> fold(Tuple2<String, Long> acc, eventClass event) 
{
    acc._1 = event.getUser();
    acc._2 += event.getOtherThing();
    return acc
}
```

To me this should be working, because all I am doing is change the values of the accumulator. However what I get is `Cannot assign value to final variable _1`. Same for `_2`. Why are these properties of `acc` final? How can I assign values to them?

**quick edit:**
Wat I could to is rust return a new Tuple instead, but this is not a nice solution in my opinion `return new Tuple2<String, Long>(event.getUser(), acc._2 + event.getOtherThing());`

**solution for flink framework:**
Use the Tuple2 of defined in flink. Import it using

```
import org.apache.flink.api.java.tuple.Tuple2;
```

and then use it with

```
acc.f0 = event.getUser();
acc.f1 += event.getByteDiff();
return acc;
```

Comment: Please provide FQN of the `Tuple2` class.

Comment: @scrutari It is the `scala.Tuple2`. I guess this is not the one that I wanted. Which one should I take?

Comment: Scala tuples are immutable. You can read about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7142838/in-scala-how-can-i-reassign-tuple-values)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know which `Tuple2` you are working with. How about return a new object:

```
Tuple2<String, Long> tuple = new Tuple2<String, Long>();
tuple._1 = event.getUser();
tuple._2 = event.getOtherThing() + acc._2;
return tuple;
```

Comment: We had the same though at the same moment. Okay, so this is a solution. Still, why can I not just change the `_1` and `_2` of `acc`?

Comment: Apparently the one of scala, which is not what I wanted...
Definition: `case class Tuple2[@scala.specialized +T1, @scala.specialized +T2](val _1 : T1, val _2 : T2) extends scala.AnyRef with scala.Product2[T1, T2] with scala.Product with scala.Serializable {`

Answer (score 3):

I don't know what kind of Tuple2 you still use, but I assume it is a scala Tuple2.
The scala Tuple2 it's immutable. You can't change the value of an Immutable object, you must to recreate it. 
Why? The scala Tuple2 is a functional programming "Data structure" so, as all concept of functional programming" it try to reduce side effect.
You can use the .copy function to recreate it as you want.
the following is an example of code:

```
 @Test
    public void test() {
        Tuple2<String,Long> tuple = new Tuple2<>("a",1l);
        Tuple2<String,Long> actual = tuple.copy(tuple._1,tuple._2+1);
        Tuple2<String,Long> expected = new Tuple2<>("a",2l);
        assertEquals(actual,expected);
    }
```

Comment: Is there a different Tuple class I can use? One that is mutable? Besides the one from flink, in mean.

Comment: I don't know. On scala-lang there are no mutable Tuple like flink. But i want suggest you to no pre-optimize your code. Try working with copy function and only after you note that your code will be slow for the creation of multiple object you start to optimize. But I don't think that this will be occur.